# Transform a Pandas Dataframe into a Table and populate values based on a condition being met?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### I have a csv file containing the list of holidays that i am reading from using pandas.read_csv method. I want to convert the states as the First Column and the unique Holidays Dates as the other columns. And populate the rows with booleans True only when there is a holiday in that state; else False.

Here is the desired dataframe:

[image]

and here is the csv that i am reading from:

### [image]

here is  my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Holidays.csv')
#print(df.head())
df = df.transpose()
print(df)
```

---

Here is the csv:

```
State   Official Leaves
Michigain   28-01-2019
Texas   30-01-2019
Florida 05-02-2019
Hawaii  04-07-2019
Arizona 04-07-2019
North Carolina  04-07-2019
Illinois    04-07-2019
Ohio    04-07-2019
Georgia 04-07-2019
Michigain   04-07-2019
Texas   04-07-2019
Florida 04-07-2019
California  04-07-2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one (long) line

```
df = df.pivot(index='State', columns='Official Leaves', values='Official Leaves') \
        .fillna(False) \
        .applymap(lambda x: True if x else False)
```

To change the column names to that date format

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns) \
                 .to_series() \
                 .apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b-%d'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I have taken a sample dataframe(since you provided an image), considering the `df` looks like:

```
print(df)

     States Official Leaves
0  Michigan      2019-01-28
1     Texas      2019-01-30
2   Florida      2019-02-05
3    Hawaii      2019-07-04
```

*Adding a column for string representation of day and month and using [`pd.crosstab()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)*

```
df['day_month']=df['Official Leaves'].dt.strftime('%b-%d')
pd.crosstab(df.States,df.day_month).astype(bool).reset_index().rename_axis(None,1)
#if you want states as index, just remove the reset_index() from the code
     States  Feb-05  Jan-28  Jan-30  Jul-04
0   Florida    True   False   False   False
1    Hawaii   False   False   False    True
2  Michigan   False    True   False   False
3     Texas   False   False    True   False
```

**Note:** If dtype for the `Official leaves` column is object , convert it to `datetime` using `df['Official Leaves']=pd.to_datetime(df['Official Leaves'])`